# Using Wp_Query without the loop?

Tags: wp-query, loop

I want to query for posts with a certain meta value. I would use the `WP_Query` but when in a loop (correct me if i am wrong.. I am learning wordpress; is it only when in loop? is the `the_post()` that sets the globals?), it changes the `global $post`.

Is it possible to loop without setting up the global values? I just want to fetch some stuff in the posts, i don't want to use `the_content`, `the_title`, etc.. just raw rows of arrays?

If I want to query `WP_Query` with meta fields conditions and expect and want only post, how do I get it? Do I still need to loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query itself doesn't change globals, however you are correct that `the_post()` does.

The most contained way to just retrieve posts (as array of results) is using [`get_posts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_posts/) function, which is wrapper around `WP_Query` and takes same arguments.

Comment: yup i am actually using `get_posts()` which is just executing `query()` of `Wp_Query`.  ok so if i don't use `the_post()` or `setup_postdata`, there's no need for me to use `wp_reset_query` or `wp_reset_postdata` right? as globals are untouched?  

btw: i am using your R Debug class which helped me a lot debugging and understanding some hooks in WP. it's great! will integrate it in my own custom framework for all my plugins development!

Comment: sidenote: i am reading that I should use `wp_reset_postdata()` instead of `wp_reset_query()` (unless i am using `query_posts()` which is not recommended)

Comment: @yeahman correct, unless you use anything that changes globals you do not need to reset afterwards. Also see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/847

Comment: thx for your help and explanations! I am starting to get more and more familiar to WP :)

Comment: and you recommend using a new instance of Wp_Query vs using the global $wp_query?

Comment: @yeahman yes, secondary queries shouldn't mess with main query

Comment: ok because I saw some examples using the global `$wp_query`. thx

Comment: It should be noted that using `the_post();` in the admin is a known bug and `wp_reset_postdata();` will not function properly. See the bug report here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18408